Read data from WIQL and write it into dataframe and then save as delta table into adls
I have a WIQL query which displays in the below way in devops` query results board
enter image description here.
I want the same result in a dataframe and I want to store it as delta table in adls
when I put the WIQL API in browser it gives me a JSON type content like below
enter image description here
I wrote this code in databricks
enter image description here
enter image description here
But, I am not getting correct output. I want an output in tables exactly like how it is in devops query result and I wanted to save it as delta table in datalake. What am I missing here?
enter image description here`
